# Using DSolve for a real part of a differential equation (Mathematica)

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I try to solve a differential equation (using DSolve) of the form:

```
Sys = {(Re[a T'[x] + b T[x]] == 0), T[1] == 3};
Sol = DSolve[Sys, T[x], x];
Plot[T[x]/.Sol, {x, 0, 1}
```

Where 'a' and 'b' are complex coefficients (non dependent of x).

I know this can't be the right syntax but I don't seem to find the right one anywhere. I can, of course, do the following:

```
Sys = {(a T'[x] + b T[x]] == 0), T[1] == 3};
Sol = DSolve[Sys, T[x], x];
Plot[Re[T[x]]/.Sol, {x, 0, 1}]
```

But this doesn't necessarily give me the same solution. How do I force Mathematica to take only the real part and solve the differential equation?

Thanks.

Comment: Try asking on mathematica.stackexchange.com.    I'm pretty sure you'll need to work with `NDSolve` .  Is `T` itself assumed real?

Comment: Yes, T is real. NDSolve is not needed as the equation has an analytical solution. The problem is that the function "Re" doesn't seem to work on differential expressions.

Comment: Just because you know there is a solution doesn't mean `DSolve` can find it. In this case even if you take `a=b=1`, although there is a trivially found real solution, `DSolve` will not find it with the `Re` function applied.

Comment: come to think, if `T` is real, cant you just do `Re[a] T'[x] + Re[b] T[x] == 0 ` ?